# Code continue executing even though firebase retrieval still not finished

Tags: swift, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to retrieve information from firebase firestore in Xcode, put it in a list, then display it in CollectionView.

In my firestore I have 2 collections, users and places 
Users collection: has user information and collection of places IDs that they visited 
Places collection : has place information including place ID

So if the user is logged in, I will display their places in CollectionView using places IDs in user’s collection to retrieve the information of places from Places collection.

So what I did is make two nested queries, one to retrieve the places IDs from user, second is to match the ID and retrieve the information from Places collection. This code worked but, it is very slow and the code continue executing and finish before all the information is retrieved so the list remains empty in the CollectionView.

```
    db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("placesList").getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for userdocument in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    self.db.collection(“Places”).document(userdocument.documentID+"").getDocument(){ (document, error) in
                        if let document = document, document.exists {
                            let place = Place(ID: document.documentID, name: document.get("name") as! String, rate: document.get("rating") as! Double, long: document.get("longitude") as! Double, lat:document.get("latitude") as! Double)

                            self.list.append(place)

                        } else {
                            print("Document does not exist")
                        }//end else
                    }
                }//end second query
        }//end else
    }// end first query
```

I don’t understand the problem with this code, is there a better way to do it ?! Or how do I stop the code from executing before finishing the queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **DispatchSemaphore**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore

more explanations here,
https://medium.com/@roykronenfeld/semaphores-in-swift-e296ea80f860